# How to use Shap with a LSTM neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, shap

I am working with keras to generate LSTM neural net model. I want to find Shapley values for each of the model's features using the shap package. The problem, of course, is that the model's LSTM layer requires a three dimensional input (samples, time steps, features), but the shap package requires a two dimensional input. Is there anyway around this problem?

Below I've included some code that reproduces the issue.

```
import numpy as np
from random import uniform

N=100

#Initlaize input/output vectors
x1=[] 
x2=[] 
x3=[]
y1=[]
y2=[]

#Generate some data
for i in range(N):
    x1.append(i/100+uniform(-.1,.1))
    x2.append(i/100+uniform(-3,5)+2)
    x3.append(uniform(0,1)/np.sqrt(i+1))
    
    y1.append(2*x1[i]-.5*x2[i]+x3[i]+uniform(-1,1))
    y2.append(x1[i]+3*x3[i]+5+uniform(-1,3))

#Convert lists to numpy arrays
x1=np.array(x1).reshape(N,1)
x2=np.array(x2).reshape(N,1)
x3=np.array(x3).reshape(N,1)

y1=np.array(y1).reshape(N,1)

#Assemble into matrices
X = np.hstack((x1, x2, x3))
Y = y1

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1]))

#Import keras functions
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM


#Lets build us a neural net!
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1,3)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',run_eagerly=())
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=2)


import shap
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

DE=shap.KernelExplainer(model.predict,shap.sample(X,10))
shap_values = DE.shap_values(X) # X is 3d numpy.ndarray
```

I have tried reshaping X into a two dimensional array in the shap_values function, but that does not work. Similarly, trying to feed a two dimensional array into the LSTM layer causes an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong model from shap package, (KernelExplainer) is used with base machine learning models but not deep models.
You need to use [DeepExplainer](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/deep_explainer/Keras%20LSTM%20for%20IMDB%20Sentiment%20Classification.html) with LSTM and any network from Keras.